# Prevent replacing html content with PJAX if a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following event listener to **pjax:beforeReplace** to check content from server and if a condition is met then do not display anything and

```
$(document).on("pjax:beforeReplace", function(e, contents) {
   var $contentBeforePut = $(contents);

   if(conditionHere) {
       // here I want to prevent put html content, I tried with:
       location.reload(true);
   }
}
```

but is not working, means that the html content is put, is visible and after that the page is reloaded.

```
$(document).on("pjax:end", function () { 
    // the code is executed even I put location.reload in beforeReplace event 
});
```

I want to reload page before put content with pjax, how to do that ?

Comment: why are you using ajax if you are reloading the page lol?

Comment: If you don't understand question or what I'm doing, please ask ...

Comment: what do you mean by *I want to reload page before put content with pjax, how to do that ?*

Comment: I provide an example to reload page, maybe a good question should be: `how to cancel putting content in HTML based on a condition ?`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).on("pjax:beforeReplace", function(e, contents) {
   var $contentBeforePut = $(contents);

   if(conditionHere) {
       // here I want to prevent put html content, I tried with:
       return false; 
   }
}
```

reference from **https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/427**

Comment: That there is suggested functionality, it won't work.